# Changing LayoutConstraint at runtime codename one

Tags: layout, constraints, codenameone

I have a container with BorderLayout and a Button with LayoutConstraint = "South". How can I change it to "North" at run time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the component from the container and add it again to the north. Call `revalidate()` or better yet `animateLayout()` e.g.

```
myBorderContainer.removeComponent(button);
myBorderContainer.addComponent(BorderLayout.NORTH, button);
myBorderContainer.animateLayout(300);
```